# STL user defined binary operations

Tags: c++, stl

I've been reading about STL and I found the following code:

```
int MyFunction(int total, int value)
{
    return total + value * value;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> integers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int result = accumulate(integers.begin(), integers.end(), 0, MyFunction);
    cout << result;
}
```

My question is: How does accumulate passes the parameters to `MyFunction`. I mean: How does the function assigns the `total` and `value` values?  I think the answer must be something simple that I am missing, but I'm really confused about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the following a possible implementation of `std::accumulate()`:

```
template<class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOperation>
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init, BinaryOperation op)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init = op(init, *first); // <-- the call
    }
    return init;
}
```

The part you are interested in is `op(init, *first)`. Since you are passing `MyFunction` as the fourth argument to the call to the `std::accumulate()` function template:

```
int MyFunction(int total, int value)
{
    return total + value * value;
}
```

Then, `op` in your case will be deduced to be of type `int(*)(int, int)` (i.e., a *pointer to a function* that takes two `int`s and returns `int`). This pointer points to your function `MyFunction()`. So, basically, `std::accumulate()` is passing `init` and `*first` as the first and second argument to the calls to `MyFunction()`, respectively.

Comment: Why op is type int(*)(int, int) ? It seems it's just like a function that returns int (not a pointer to a function)

Comment: @Beats2019 The fourth argument that you are passing to `std::accumulate()`– i.e., `MyFunction` – is the address of your function `MyFunction`. Therefore, `BinaryOperation` is deduced to the type `int(*)(int, int)`.

Comment: @Beats2019 Actually, passing a function *by value* – i.e., the parameter call is `BinaryOperation op` instead of `BinaryOperation& op` – results in a *type decay* when it comes to template type deduction: the template argument `BinaryOperation` is deduced to be a pointer to a function of the passed type.

Comment: you're right, functions can only be passed as parameters with the use of pointers; they can't be passed by value. Good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at cppreference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

```
template<class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOperation>
constexpr // since C++20
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init, 
             BinaryOperation op)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init = op(std::move(init), *first); // std::move since C++20
    }
    return init;
}
```

Should make it clear what happens

Answer (score 0):

`std::accumulate` always passes a fixed number of arguments, so it knowns how to call your function, because if it took different number of arguments the code wouldn't compile. 
As for how it can be implemented, cppreference has some nice examples - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate - for example:

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
constexpr // since C++20
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T 
init)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init = std::move(init) + *first; // std::move since C++20
    }
    return init;
}
```